# How to trace calls to library from library?

Tags: debugging, ltrace

I have an program that calls libcurl, and libcurl calls libgssapi_krb5.

If I want to debug calls to libcurl, then ltrace works.

But now I want to debug calls to libgssapi_krb5, then `ltrace my_program` does not give out anything.

Comment: `ltrace` ought to be tracing all calls to functions in libraries dynamically loaded by the process at startup. You may have problems tracing calls to libraries that were loaded into the running process by `libdl`. Is that how libcurl loads libgssapi_krb5? More recent versions of `ltrace` may be fixed (see https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2012-0926.html ) so that the -x option can be used to trace functions in dlopen'ed libraries.

Comment: I am using 0.5.3, which does not work as wanted....

Comment: A workaround might be to make a call to something, anything, in libgssapi_krb5 in your own code so that the library gets dynamically loaded at startup.